# Inserting a MySQL record into a table with an array of field names and an array of values

Tags: wpdb

I see this in the Codex:

```
$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );
```

I'm using this type of code and it works:

```
$wpdb->query( 
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO `table` (`field1`,`field2`,`field3`,`field4`) VALUES (%d,%d,%d,%s) ", 
        $_REQUEST['field1'], $_REQUEST['field2'], $_REQUEST['field3'], $_REQUEST['field4']
    )
);
```

I have a form that has 20 optional fields, so I don't want to just insert them all because some may not pass any values. I'd like to check them first and then only add the code to the table if it was filled in.

Can I put that last section:

```
$_REQUEST['field1'], $_REQUEST['field2'], $_REQUEST['field3'], $_REQUEST['field4']
```

as an array, so that I could build it dynamically, like this:

```
$_sqlCode = "";
$_sqlValues = array();
if(isset($_REQUEST['field1']) && $_REQUEST['field1'] != "") {
    if($_sqlCode) { $_sqlCode .= ', `field1`';} else { $_sqlCode = '`field1`';}
    $_field1Value = $_REQUEST['field1'];
    $_sqlValues["$_field1Value"] = $_field1Value;
}
```

and do that for each of the fields in the form, for the table?

Would it be easier just to have an array built with `key=>value`, then do a `foreach` loop, and build the string like that? I don't know if I can put an array into the values section, or how I'd do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass an array of values. This is explained in the codex under [Protect Queries Against SQL Injection Attacks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks)

> **value_parameter** (int|string|array) The value to substitute into the placeholder. Many values may be passed by simply passing more arguments in a sprintf()-like fashion. **Alternatively the second argument can be an array containing the values as in PHP's vsprintf() function**.

```
$metakey = "Harriet's Adages";
$metavalue = "WordPress' database interface is like Sunday Morning: Easy.";

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta
        ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value )
        VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )
    ", 
        array(
        10, 
        $metakey, 
        $metavalue
    ) 
) );
```

Comment: Yeah, I seen that in the codex, but how do I build the string to ONLY have values that were entered into the form fields? so I'm not just putting empty ones in there?
Like in my example.  This is to insert data into a table I made, not pages or posts.

Comment: your example looks like it would work. have you tried it and encountered a problem?

Comment: Okay, I tried it, and it worked, it did not break my site. :) wahoo. I ran 3 tests, all worked great. Thanks for letting me know it should work, it is a live site, so I did not want to break it. Thanks.